# python.exe is 0kb and cmd gives "This app can't run on your PC. To find a version check with the software publisher."

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, python

I'm using windows 10 64-bit. I had python 2.7 (python-2.7.15.amd64.msi) running normally on my PC from October 2018. Suddenly, when I execute `python` in cmd, I get the message:

"This app can't run on your PC. To find a version for your PC check with software publisher".

I noticed that the python.exe is set 0KB, as shown below:

[image: screenshot]

I've tried to tweak admin rights and some other workarounds found on other Stack Overflow / sites. But none seem to fix the problem.

Could you please advise.

Answer (score 1):

> Could you please advice.

The Python executable in question is corrupt.  Due to the fact, a Windows executable cannot be 0 KB, the file is incomplete and/or corrupt.

You should simply uninstall and reinstall Python. The error message you received is common and typically happens when Windows doesn’t recognize the header information within an executable.